# How to post an image as a request with Flask Server API in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I want to post a request to a Python-based API that has an image in its body. I have tried to send data with 5 methods:

1. await http.post()

```
   final api = Uri.parse("https://e8f628d7.ngrok.io/detections");
   Map<String, dynamic> body = {'images': image};
    final response = await http.post(
      api,
      body: body,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseJson);
    }
```

2. Client().post()

```
     Map<String, dynamic> body = {'images': image};
     var client = new http.Client();
       client.post("https://e8f628d7.ngrok.io/detections",body: body).then((response) {
         print("Post " + response.statusCode.toString());
       });
```

3. dio
4. MultipartRequest

```
    final api = Uri.parse("https://e8f628d7.ngrok.io/detections");
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image.openRead()));
    var length = await image.length();
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", api);
    var multipartFileSign = new http.MultipartFile(
        'profile_pic', stream, length,
        filename: path.basename(image.path));
    request.files.add(multipartFileSign);
    // send
    var response = await request.send();
    print(response.statusCode);
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
```

5. Link of [DELETED]First Answer to this question:

```
    if (image == null) return;
    String base64Image = base64Encode(image.readAsBytesSync());
    http.post(api, body: {
      'images': base64Image,
    }).then((res) {
      print(res.statusCode);
      print(json.decode(res.body));
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }
```

I am able to send the image and am getting a 200 success response. But, I am not sure if the image is getting altered or any problem happens while sending the image as the response is empty whereas it should have some sort of response.
This is my app.py from with which my server works:

```
import time
from absl import app, logging
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from yolov3_tf2.models import (
    YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny
)
from yolov3_tf2.dataset import transform_images, load_tfrecord_dataset
from yolov3_tf2.utils import draw_outputs
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify, send_from_directory, abort
import os

# customize your API through the following parameters
classes_path = './data/labels/coco.names'
weights_path = './weights/yolov3.tf'
tiny = False                    # set to True if using a Yolov3 Tiny model
size = 416                      # size images are resized to for model
output_path = './detections/'   # path to output folder where images with detections are saved
num_classes = 80                # number of classes in model

# load in weights and classes
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

if tiny:
    yolo = YoloV3Tiny(classes=num_classes)
else:
    yolo = YoloV3(classes=num_classes)

yolo.load_weights(weights_path).expect_partial()
print('weights loaded')

class_names = [c.strip() for c in open(classes_path).readlines()]
print('classes loaded')

# Initialize Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

# API that returns JSON with classes found in images
@app.route('/detections', methods=['POST'])
def get_detections():
    raw_images = []
    images = request.files.getlist("images")
    image_names = []
    for image in images:
        image_name = image.filename
        image_names.append(image_name)
        image.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_name))
        img_raw = tf.image.decode_image(
            open(image_name, 'rb').read(), channels=3)
        raw_images.append(img_raw)

    num = 0

    # create list for final response
    response = []

    for j in range(len(raw_images)):
        # create list of responses for current image
        responses = []
        raw_img = raw_images[j]
        num+=1
        img = tf.expand_dims(raw_img, 0)
        img = transform_images(img, size)

        t1 = time.time()
        boxes, scores, classes, nums = yolo(img)
        t2 = time.time()
        print('time: {}'.format(t2 - t1))

        print('detections:')
        for i in range(nums[0]):
            print('\t{}, {}, {}'.format(class_names[int(classes[0][i])],
                                            np.array(scores[0][i]),
                                            np.array(boxes[0][i])))
            responses.append({
                "class": class_names[int(classes[0][i])],
                "confidence": float("{0:.2f}".format(np.array(scores[0][i])*100))
            })
        response.append({
            "image": image_names[j],
            "detections": responses
        })
        img = cv2.cvtColor(raw_img.numpy(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        img = draw_outputs(img, (boxes, scores, classes, nums), class_names)
        cv2.imwrite(output_path + 'detection' + str(num) + '.jpg', img)
        print('output saved to: {}'.format(output_path + 'detection' + str(num) + '.jpg'))

    #remove temporary images
    for name in image_names:
        os.remove(name)
    try:
        return jsonify({"response":response}), 200
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)

# API that returns image with detections on it
@app.route('/image', methods= ['POST'])
def get_image():
    image = request.files["images"]
    image_name = image.filename
    image.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_name))
    img_raw = tf.image.decode_image(
        open(image_name, 'rb').read(), channels=3)
    img = tf.expand_dims(img_raw, 0)
    img = transform_images(img, size)

    t1 = time.time()
    boxes, scores, classes, nums = yolo(img)
    t2 = time.time()
    print('time: {}'.format(t2 - t1))

    print('detections:')
    for i in range(nums[0]):
        print('\t{}, {}, {}'.format(class_names[int(classes[0][i])],
                                        np.array(scores[0][i]),
                                        np.array(boxes[0][i])))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_raw.numpy(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img = draw_outputs(img, (boxes, scores, classes, nums), class_names)
    cv2.imwrite(output_path + 'detection.jpg', img)
    print('output saved to: {}'.format(output_path + 'detection.jpg'))

    # prepare image for response
    _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.png', img)
    response = img_encoded.tostring()

    #remove temporary image
    os.remove(image_name)

    try:
        return Response(response=response, status=200, mimetype='image/png')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I try to send the same image directly through Postman and get the desired response but when I do it with the flutter app, I don't get it. Is there any possibility of the image getting altered or modified? And, is there any other method in which I can send the image to the API other than the above 3?

Comment: It would normally be sent with a multipart request. I don't see your code trying that.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you for noticing. I did use Multipart request. I have updated my question!

Comment: Please refactor your multipart code to use this convenience method: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/fromPath.html which removes about 4 other lines. Then let us know the result.

Comment: @RichardHeap MultipartFile.fromPath() doesn't work. There is no such function. I have checked it. MutipartFile.fromBytes() and MultipartFile.fromString() are the only functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are using a good version of `http`. There was a regression recently that broke multipart form. It's safest for now to hard code the exact version in `pubspec.yaml` (You might want to look in `pubspec.lock` to see what version you were using to confirm that it was one of the ones with the error.)

```
  http: 0.12.0+4
```

Then try this:

```
main() async {
  http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));

  request.files.add(
    await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'images',
      File('kitten1.jpg').path,
      contentType: MediaType('application', 'jpeg'),
    ),
  );

  http.StreamedResponse r = await request.send();
  print(r.statusCode);
  print(await r.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much. I was checking with the code new http.Multipart.fromPath() but then I noticed that we need await to work with http.MultipartFile.fromPath. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: Indeed. FromPath is a static, not a named constructor, so you would not use new with it. If fact, you should drop the new keyword everywhere for better style.

Comment: What if my response has an image in it? My server sends an image with image.toString(). So, the print(r.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).join()) gives me bad UTF-8 error.

Comment: Why would you encoded an image as a string? What are you trying to return from the server? Probably best to compose a new question with where you are stuck.

Comment: Yup, you are right. I will look into that. Thank you for all the help over the span of 2 days.

Comment: no matter what I did always my error is ``E/flutter (26055): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400]``